# Entity Framework many-to-many update error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a many-to-many relation in my database. Everything works fine while updating entities, except deleting the old objects from the collection throws an error.

```
public void Update(CourseGroup courseGroupToUpdate)
{
    try
    {
        var courseGroup = _context.CourseGroups
                                  .Include("PricingSchedule")
                                  .Include("GroupCourses")
                                  .AsNoTracking()
                                  .SingleOrDefault(cg => cg.Id == courseGroupToUpdate.Id && 
                                                         cg.IsActive == true);

        var coursesToDelete = courseGroup.GroupCourses.ExceptBy(courseGroupToUpdate.GroupCourses, cg => cg.CourseId).ToList();
        var coursesToAdd = courseGroupToUpdate.GroupCourses.ExceptBy(courseGroup.GroupCourses, cg => cg.CourseId).ToList();

        _context.Entry(courseGroupToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _context.GroupCourses.RemoveRange(coursesToDelete);
        _context.GroupCourses.AddRange(coursesToAdd);
        _context.Entry(courseGroupToUpdate.PricingSchedule).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The above code works fine except for this line:

```
 _context.GroupCourses.RemoveRange(coursesToDelete);
```

When it executes, this error is thrown:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, Haseeb. Could you add the definitions for the `CourseGroup` and `GroupCourses` entities? That would help me better understand how the entities relate to each other.,

Answer (score 0):

I believe your use of ToList() is unattaching your entities from your object context. You can either remove the superfluous ToList() call or you can reattach the entities manually.

Try this:

```
var coursesToDelete = courseGroup.GroupCourses.ExceptBy(courseGroupToUpdate.GroupCourses, cg => cg.CourseId);
_context.GroupCourses.RemoveRange(coursesToDelete);
```

or this:

```
var coursesToDelete = courseGroup.GroupCourses.ExceptBy(courseGroupToUpdate.GroupCourses, cg => cg.CourseId).ToList();

context.Attach(coursesToDelete);
_context.GroupCourses.RemoveRange(coursesToDelete);
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't the `AsNoTracking` option mean that you won't have the objects in the `ObjectStateManager`?  I think removing that might solve your problem.

Try your query without the `AsNoTracking` call, and see what happens.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19769874)

Comment: @James_Parsons How does this not answer the question? She both suggested an update to the code defect and explained why it likely causes an issue.

Comment: @Ann L. if i remove AsNoTracking() I got following error "Attaching an entity of type 'ScormEngine.Core.Models.Domain.CourseGroup' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value........"

Comment: @HaseebKhan Which line of code throws the "Attaching an entity of type ..." error?  My guess is that it's the `.AddRange` method.

Comment: @HaseebKhan Where is the information in `courseGroupToUpdate` coming from? Was it originally from the database, and then modified? Was `AsNoTracking()` used when it was retrieved?

Comment: Yes, when it was originally retrieved I used AsNoTracking(). But anyway I solved it I modify the object which I retrieved from DB and saved it. This way I don't need AsNoTracking()

Comment: Thanks for your help